# Way to create only one reference for all my js files in my html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

I have a lot of js files in my View(html page),and I wonder if there is a way to
combine all my js reference to one ref .

Comment: What technologies are you using? Are you using just plain html/JavaScript or are you using .Net MVC?

Comment: You can grunt All js files,I mean minify the files

Comment: If you always load all of them, why not make them one file when you minify them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using .NET MVC, have a look at
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

If you are developing using plain JS & HTML, **gulp** could be an alternative with the **gulp-bundle** package.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    bundle = require('gulp-bundle');

gulp.task('bundle', bundle('./app/*.js', {
    appDir: 'app',
    buildDir: 'dist',
    minify: true
}));
```

which would take all js files in the app directory, bundle them and minify to the 'dist' directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to compile your javascript files and create a bundle file.

Webpack has a lot of documentation and tutorials.